# Fire Button on Hyperlink Click

Tags: javascript, html

My form has two buttons: `delete` and `play`. Currently, the user must use the submit buttons at the bottom of the form to perform either of these tasks. I'd like to add a hyperlink to the top of the page with an `onclick` function that fires the appropriate submit button.

Here's what I'm working with. Currently, the hyperlink isn't working at all.

**Hyperlink at top of page:**

```
<a href='#' onlick='document.getElementById('playlist').click()'>test</a>
```

**And here is my form with its submit buttons.**

```
<form id = 'allverses' name= 'allverses' action='' method='POST'>
<button name="delete" type="SUBMIT" class="deletebutton" id="delete" value="delete" action="POST">
<button name="playlist" type="SUBMIT" class="playbutton" id="playlist" value="play" action="POST">
</form>
```

Comment: Your main mistake that I can see is that you used the same quote for both the tag and the string inside the tag. Try alternating,  put `playlist` around double quotes or an escaped quote `\'`

Comment: You have a typo: your link has `onlick` instead of `onclick`.

Comment: Use a tool that could correct your syntax. Visual Studio Code would be fine

Comment: You need first of all stick to a convention for your syntax and these errors will not occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Syntax Errors:**

1. onlick should be onclick.
2. buttons end tag were not properly setup.

**With correct syntax the following code works fine.**

```html
<a href='#' onclick="document.getElementById('playlist').click();">test</a>

<form id='allverses' name='allverses' action='' method='POST'>
<button name="delete" type="SUBMIT" class="deletebutton" id="delete" value="delete" action="POST" />
<button name="playlist" type="SUBMIT" class="playbutton" id="playlist" value="play" action="POST" />
</form>
```

Comment: This appears to be a copy/paste of the code from the question. Why did you post it as an answer?

Comment: there were some syntax errors, that i corrected and its now working fine.

Comment: Perhaps you could *explain the problem* instead of expressing your answer in the form of a game of spot-the-difference. (And if the problem was caused by a typo then it should be closed as off-topic and not answered anyway).

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @Quentin now fine ?

Comment: In HTML it is allowed to put a `/` and the end of a boolean element (it is utterly pointless, but it stops the code being invalid for people who got into the habit when writing XHTML). The `<button>` element is not a boolean element, the `/` is not allowed and the end tag is mandatory. As mentioned, a typo question where `lick` was typed instead of `click` should be closed as off-topic, not answered.